# How to configure JBoss 7.1 on windows server 2008 AWS Amazon EC2 to access java application via a domain, elastic IP and Route 53?

Tags: amazon-ec2, jboss7.x, elastic-ip

How do I access a java web application hosted on Amazon AWS EC2, windows 2008 server, jboss 7.1, through an internet domain using java web server and jboss 7.1? I can access the application on localhost: 8080/webcontent server but I can not set up to access a java web application externally via an internet domain.
I have already created rules on security group 80 (HTTP) 0.0.0.0 / 0, 3389 (RDP) 0.0.0.0 / 0, 8080 (* HTTP).
I've created an elastic IP and associated the instance of my windows server 2008.
I've already configured the service Route 53 to my domain and have changed the DNS settings on the hosting service that manages my domain.

What else do I need to configure?

Someone help me please.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem.

Able to access the application from outside the server configuration in placing this file standalone.xml the Jboss:

Edit standalone/configuration/standalone.xml

```
<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="127.0.0.1"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <any-address/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>
```